# Subclass UIView to have two labels

Tags: ios, class, uiview, label, subclass

I am working on an app that uses many UIViews of the same size, with the same two labels (albeit with different text in the labels), and I figure I should use some abstraction here and make a UIView Subclass with the labels built in.

I need the class to create views of the same size and with two labels in the same place within that view. Extra points if I can round the corners of the views.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Take this in stages. Start by creating your own custom `UIView` class. Maybe set the background color so you can set it. Update your code to use this custom view.

Once that is done and working, go to the next level. Have the custom view create two labels and add them to itself. Start with hardcoded text in the labels. Play around with get the size and position correct. This can be done with proper frame sizing and `autoresizingMask` values or you can override the `layoutSubviews` method to manually position and size the labels.

Once that works, update the class to provide properties or methods that allow users of this class to set the text of the two labels.

Lastly, setup the view's layer so it uses rounded corners and maybe a border.

Breaking down a problem like this into small steps allows you to get each little bit working. Don't try to code it all at once and then try to figure out why it doesn't work.

This also allows you to ask more detailed questions on SO if you get stuck. Or better yet, it narrows your focus so you can read the docs and search for related samples dealing with that one detail instead of the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I have to reuse a view in several places I create a custom UIView with a .xib file for it (it is very easy to setup the UI with .xib files) and I create a method that loads the nib and creates a new instance of that class. I also provide extra setup methods for it, so in your case I would create something like:

1. A subclass of UIView with a .xib file and I would add two labels on the required position.
2. Create `@propertie(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *fitstLabel;` and one for the second label. (Be careful when you link the outlets (link them to the view not file's owner)
3. Create a `+(YourViewName*)instantiateViews;` method or whatever you want to call it and in the implementation do something like:

   +(YourViewName *)instatiateViews {
       NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TheXibFileName" owner:nil option:nil];
       return [views objectAtIndex:0];
   }
4. Add other setup methods to fit your needs.

For rounded corners of your view you have to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and you can create a method  like:

```
-(void)setViewsRoundedCornersWithCornerRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
     self.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
}
```

And now, when you want a new instance of this custom view you only have to call:

```
YourViewName *customView = [YourViewName instantiateViews];
```

after that you can call all your setup methods.